# Install and configure mod_rewrite for Apache 2 on Mac OS X for Zend Framework 2

Tags: macos, apache, zend-framework2

I getting started with zend framework 2 and they have a [prerequisite](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html) of an installation and configuration of mod_rewrite for apache.  Apache 2.2.22 came pre-installed on Mac OS X 10.8.2.  Is there an easy way to install and configure mod_rewrite for apache?

The only help I have come across suggests to recompile apache.  Is this the only way?

Comment: Does this not work for you? http://serverfault.com/questions/113853/getting-mod-rewrite-working-on-os-x-snow-leopard (first answer, Keith Norman)

Comment: This question is not a programming question and belongs to ServerFault.

Comment: @DanielM I agree it's not a programming question, but it doesn't belong on ServerFault.  In fact, it's hard to say _where_ questions like this belong now.  Any time I ask a question on ServerFault like this it either gets ignored or closed...or _both_.  Maybe it belongs on "Ask Different?"  Who knows..

Answer (score 157, accepted):

To check that mod_rewrite and PHP are enabled, look at */etc/apache2/httpd.conf* and ensure that these lines:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

are uncommented.

Also ensure that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` within the `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">` section.

After making these changes, restart Apache with: `sudo apachectl restart`

If you then put your project within the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder, then it should work.

Comment: Worked for me after uncommenting php5_module and adding AllowOverride All as suggested. Tnx a lot :)

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo apachectl restart` after editing httpd.conf

Comment: This worked for me, I was seeing weird 404 errors after a clean drush drupal 7 install and this fixed it

Comment: And add ```Indexes``` in Options [Indexes] FollowSymLinks Multiviews

Comment: Worked for me by just uncommenting *rewrite_module*, adding AllowOverride All and restarting apache.

Comment: AllowOverride to All worked for me. i already enabled mod_rewrite but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 13):

If you are serving your site from `~/Sites`, the trick for me was modifying my `/private/etc/apache2/users/USERNAME.conf` file.  Initially, the content was:

```
<Directory "/Users/USERNAME/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Changing `AllowOverride` to `all` and then restarting the server with a quick `sudo apachectl restart` enabled me to start using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` files living beneath `~/Sites`.

Comment: After changing this setting, I'm getting 403 forbidden and the error is : `Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/xliang/Sites/flight/event` Any ideas? BTW I'm running my site from ~/Sites

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Rob Allen's response, both line numbers are located around 168 and 169 (to save you some time from scrolling the 500+ lines of text). Also, to explain what each line does exactly:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

> This overrides the default settings for any .htaccess files used at the document root

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

> This allows URL rewrites for permalinks

Source: [link](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to http-vhosts.conf file

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to reload your apache using this commande

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

yosemite os x should be like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin enzo@enzolutions.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/enzo/www/drupal8"

    ServerName drupal8

    #ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    <Directory /Users/enzo/www/drupal8>
        Require all granted
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/drupal8-error.log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/drupal8-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

gotten from [this blog post](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/10/19/apache-issues-after-upgrade-to-mac-os-x-yosemite/)

Answer (score 0):

My chose

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin user@domain.ru
    DocumentRoot "/Users/r00we/sites/buytocoins.ru"
    ServerName site.ru
    ServerAlias www.site.ru
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myfaketestsite.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/myfaketestsite.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this also might raise this issue:

Make sure `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` links to the **same** folder in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as following:

[image]

This is an innocent mistake if you copy the virtual host block from existing sites.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Rob Allen's answer *sounds* right, but I've never used the default installation of Apache on my Mac so I can't verify.  I would recommend either [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/).

It took me a little while to get Zend Server CE configured and running correctly on my Mac, but that was version 4 and it was buggy and either way it was well worth it.  Conversely, version 5.6 of ZSCE seems to be much better!

[Some notes on Zend Server CE for Mac OS X](http://akrabat.com/php/some-notes-on-zend-server-ce-for-mac-os-x/)

If you go with MAMP, it should be a very quick install, aside from [configuring virtual hosts](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php).

Note that both of these come with **mod_rewrite** already installed.

Comment: i havent' had much luck with zend server ce and mac os x lion

Comment: @b_dubb sorry to hear that.  what kind of problems have you been had?

Comment: problems with controller / action uri's not being found.  i've set up my vhost and htaccess. i add an Admin controller with the zf.sh tool and get zf error message when i go to my project uri. zf thinks my /~username ... is a controller.  blarg

Comment: hmm well I still use snow leopard so I'm not certain, but either way I never used the zf tool stuff, I always did it manually.