# Install and Enable Mod_Rewrite Module in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using Bluehost as my hosting provider and trying to connect a script. After uploading the files and scripts through FTP I got these error messages:

> URL rewriting must be enabled on your server
>   Install and enable the mod_rewrite module in Apache.

And then:

> Your web server can handle HTML post data
>   Disable the security rules that prevents HTML POST.

I've tried searching on how to enable it, but all I get is tutorials to do this through Ubuntu, and other tutorials that haven't helped. Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Only hosting provider can do this for you. If you have WHM OR VPS then you can do it. If it is shared hosting then it can't be done from your end, contact Bluehost and they will do it.

Answer (score 2):

In apache, you need one fiel ".htaccess" , search about that file on the google and try to understand it.
In ubuntu,there is some command are available to make url rewritable.

```
command-1. sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

this command will turn on the url rewriting.after then restart your apache server.

```
command-2.(restart apache) sudo service apache2 restart
```

now you can see the if mod_rewrite is enable or not
make one php file

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

if you open this file in the browser you can search **mod_rewrite** and you can check it that mod_rewrite is there or not.I have also attached the screen shot so you can get that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLJNL.png)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified I'm not using Ubuntu I'm on Mac's os

Comment: please refer this , i hope it would help you out. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592215/install-and-configure-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-on-mac-os-x-for-zend-framework-2)