# Codeigniter using MAMP on Mac - how to remove index.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have tried all the possible solutions that I found here in similar questions but with no luck!

I just want to remove the `index.php` from the URI.

I am using Codeigniter 3, on macOS High Sierra and MAMP PRO 5.2.

In the .htaccess file which is located inside application folder (root) I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have also tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

After that I have tried the followings in the config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/';
```

or

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

and also

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

or

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or the issue is with my Apache server.

Comment: `.htaccess` should not be in in your `application folder (root)`.  It should be in `public_html/`, where `index.php` is.

Comment: @Don'tPanic You are right! Thank you! If you want you can create an answer explaining this! Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess should not be in in application folder (root) but it should be in public_html/, where index.php is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that everything is ok with `mamp` out of the box, so lets say its a codeigniter's configuration problem.

First of all `.htaccess` file is located in `FCPATH` beside `index.php` file and the first four lines from the docs works just fine.

Secondly, you need to set you `base_url` in `config.php` manually till the path of you `FCPATH` again the path of your `index.php`.

Thirdly, but not needed actually, remove `index_page` value in `config.php`.

Supposingly you did all of that already, then you need to check your `mamp` configuration cause its not codeigniter's problem then.

You got to enable `mod_rewrite` in apache.

Comment: how to enable the mod_rewrite? I tried to work with terminal but do not allow me to use sudo command!

Comment: @chrysst have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615227/5609501) and let me know.

Comment: Finally the issue was the location of the .htaccess file.. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `https.conf` file, like with any Apache server. This is the best way to edit settings like this. The file is located at `~/Applications/conf/apache/https.conf`